# What is the meaning of $\|f-g\|_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval and let $f;g \in C[I]$.

Is $\|f-g\|_{\infty}:=\rho (f;g):=\underset{x \in I}{\mathrm{max}} |(f-g)(x)|$, the maximum distance between $f$ and $g$ on $I$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Norm

Comment: Is $I$ a closed interval?  If not, then $\max{x\in I} |(f-g)(x)|$ may not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be 
$$
\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)-g(x)|
$$
Note that we take the $\sup $ since we have no guarantee that the max will exist ($I$ may not be closed).

Comment: While this is a correct statement, I don't see how this answers the question, which asks about the *meaning* of $\|f-g\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: By "meaning" I meant the definition.